# form view in excel for a record

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a sheet in excel that is basically like a database (yes it has to be in excel unfortunately) and I want to design a simple form to display the records (the different column values in the rows). Usually MS is good with making widgets to do this but I cant seem to figure out how to write it in VBA (easily)

Basically I have a list of Names and ID#'s then some other columns that need to be filled in (address, order # etc) but I'd like the user to do this via a form rather than typing in excel. I created a small form in VBA, but now I cant link the columns to the textboxes in the form.

Anyone know of any code I can plug and play to do this.

Specifically I am using a ComboBox (for the list of names) and then a for loop searching through it to find the selection and updating data. But its a real pain.

plus I cant figure out how to put in a 'Next' button, which is really annoying me. Does anyone know how to change the comboBox value to the next row, if it is linked via RowSource

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the `Form` feature? You can find under the commands you can add to your QuickAccess toolbar.

Check this helpful [tutorial](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/datamanagementinexcel/ss/090717_data_form.htm) for additional details.